# Double-trace operators in CFT?

Tags: operators, conformal-field-theory, trace

What is the conceptual difference between so called "single-trace" and "double-trace" (or "multi-trace") operators e.g., in a Conformal Field Theory?

Comment: The answer is given e.g. in section 4.1.1 of
> https://arxiv.org/pdf/1610.01318.pdf